# Redirect already logged user in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm using this Java configuration in order to manage http routes with Spring Boot + Spring Security:

```
@Override   
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()           
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/landing")
            .permitAll()
        //...
}
```

Now, I've just one question: how can I redirect an already logged user from /login to /landing page? Have I to check this case inside the controller or in the config class as shown above?

Comment: Can you describe the flow you want in a bit more detail, and what you are seeing instead? It looks to me like a user visiting "/login" will get a form, and if he submits successfully, he is forwarded to "/landing". Is that not what you want.

Comment: If this user is already logged and go on "/login", I'd like that the system redirect him on "/landing".

Answer (score 3):

You could handle that in your /login" endpoint. How about something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(Principal principal) {
    if (principal!=null && ((Authentication)principal).isAuthenticated()) {
        return "forward:/landing";
    }
    return "login";
}
```

Or I guess you could add a filter (seems like overkill).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
        return "redirect:/landing";
    } else return "login";
}
```

And can change this:

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()           
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
```

For this:

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/public/**", "/signup").permitAll()
```